# Ajax load more on scroll load wrong images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show `Instagram` photo based on User Account and give user choice to view same based on `TagName` which are listed in `dropdown`.

I am using `instfeedjs` plugin for this and I am able to show user based images on when page is loaded  and give user and option view tags based images selected from `drop-down`. this is working

problem is with loading more images on scrolling to the bottom of page.

Load more works but always loads the images from `instagram user account` not from the relevant tag which user had selected.

My logic seems to be wrong.

Codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpWVVy?editors=001

```
//Set up instafeed
var feedAccount = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
        userId: 11175379,
        accessToken: '11175379.467ede5.f5ec3337edc941678b80d5eac0310213',
    links: true,
    limit: 12,
    target: 'instafeed',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    useHttp: true,
    template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 cccc"><div class="photo-box"><div class="image-wrap"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}"></a><div class="likes">{{likes}} Likes</div></div></div></div>'
});

//// call feed.next() on button click
//$('#loadmore').on('click', function () {
//    feed.next();
//});

feedAccount.run();


$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) 
        feedAccount.next();
});
```

I want to achieve following

1. On Page load `Instagram` User based images show and should load more images from the same account when site visitor scrolls down the page. (WORKING)
2. Second, When user select the `tag` from drop-down then it should show relevant tag based images (This part is working). and when user scrolls down the page it should load more image related to same tag selected. But this this case it load images from User Account.
3. Third, When user click on Refresh button it should reset to default value like on page load and show user account based images

Not sure how to fix this, I tried few thing it either doesn't works or breaks the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this condition to scroll function

```
if($('select').val()!=""){
feedTags.next();
}
else
{
feedAccount.next();
}
```

OR

You can use single object for the records **feedAccount**

check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVyyrR?editors=001

Comment: Thanks, This works only when i change tag or click refresh button. by default on page load loading more images doesn't work.. I will add one more condition to it..

Comment: ok ... add **$("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;** to refresh button